# PostgreSQL - Get value from from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Get the average traffic from last week data per **WEEK** number and get the traffic data for last week **Traffic(D-7)**

For example if date = 5/13/2023, need to output traffic data (**Traffic(D-7)**) for date = 5/6/2023

[image]

I manage to get the Average but no idea how to retrieve the date-7 data and output it altogether

```
create table a
(
date  varchar(50),
Tname varchar(50),
Week varchar(5),
Traffic float
)

insert into  a values ('5/1/2023', 'ID1', '18', 7.98)
insert into  a values ('5/2/2023', 'ID1', '18', 4.44)
insert into  a values ('5/3/2023', 'ID1', '18', 5.66)
insert into  a values ('5/4/2023', 'ID1', '18', 10.01)
insert into  a values ('5/5/2023', 'ID1', '18', 9.41)
insert into  a values ('5/6/2023', 'ID1', '18', 6.71)
insert into  a values ('5/7/2023', 'ID1', '18', 8.24)
insert into  a values ('5/8/2023', 'ID1', '19', 8.97)
insert into  a values ('5/9/2023', 'ID1', '19', 6.74)
insert into  a values ('5/10/2023', 'ID1', '19', 6.45)
insert into  a values ('5/11/2023', 'ID1', '19', 9.33)
insert into  a values ('5/12/2023', 'ID1', '19', 8.08)
insert into  a values ('5/13/2023', 'ID1', '19', 8.36)


SELECT date, Tname, Week,
AVG(Traffic) OVER(PARTITION BY Week) AS AVTraffic
FROM a
ORDER BY week
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/538b7/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to fix your flaws in your table schema design, and declare:

- dates with the "*DATE*" type (instead of `VARCHAR(50)`)
- week values with the `INT` type (instead of `VARCHAR(5)`)
- traffic values with the `DECIMAL` type (instead of `FLOAT`)

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
    DATE      DATE,
    Tname     VARCHAR(50),
    Week      INT,
    Traffic   DECIMAL(4,2)
);
```

Once you've carried it out, you can solve this problem by:

- creating a ranking value for each day of the week in your weeks, using `EXTRACT` on your date
- extracting your traffic value from previous week with `LAG`, by partitioning on your ranking created at previous step, and ordering on the week_number.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date, Tname, Week, Traffic,
           ROUND(AVG(Traffic) OVER(PARTITION BY Week), 2) AS AVGTraffic,
           EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date) - 1                  AS week_day
    FROM tab
)
SELECT date, Tname, Week, 
       LAG(Traffic) OVER(PARTITION BY week_day ORDER BY Week) AS prevweek_traffic,
       AVGTraffic
FROM cte
ORDER BY Week, week_day
```

And if you realize that you may have holes among your weeks (..., week 17, week 18, week 20, week 21, ...) and specifically want values from the exact previous week (that may be missing), you can add a filter on the `LAG` function, that checks if week and previous week are consecutive:

```
...
CASE WHEN LAG(Week) OVER(PARTITION BY week_day ORDER BY Week) = Week-1
     THEN LAG(Traffic) OVER(PARTITION BY week_day ORDER BY Week) 
END
...
```

(in place of `LAG(Traffic) OVER(...)` only)

**Output**:

| date | tname | week | prevweek_traffic avgtraffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-03T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-04T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-05T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-06T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-07T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 18 | null |
| 2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 7.98 |
| 2023-05-09T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 4.44 |
| 2023-05-10T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 5.66 |
| 2023-05-11T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 10.01 |
| 2023-05-12T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 9.41 |
| 2023-05-13T00:00:00.000Z | ID1 | 19 | 6.71 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2gjVshR8TUjgbEsZF54Av/1).

This query allows any kind of holes in your data, if that's a needed requirement.

Note: The last `ORDER BY` clause is not needed. It's there just for visualization purposes.

Comment: Week and weekday can be extracted from the date using EXTRACT. That might give more reliable results around the end of the year and the beginning of the new year

Comment: That's smart, I'll take a note of that, thanks.

Comment: Was wondering if there's a way to automatically initialize week values using `DEFAULT` with `EXTRACT` inside the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and avoid specifying them one-by-one inside the `INSERT` statement...

Comment: What's the difference between
EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date) - 1 and EXTRACT(Week FROM date) 

If I use EXTRACT(Week ....), it's getting the value of the previous row and not the value from previous week

Comment: ISODOW extracts the week-day (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), while WEEK extracts the week in the year (in range 1-56), that's the difference.

Comment: I see, that's why it's getting previous row when I use Extract Week. Thanks lemon!

Comment: @lemon I assume it is a simple keying mistake (on keypad) but week in the year range 1-53.

Comment: Yes, definitely 53 weeks in a year, key mistake. @Belayer

Answer (score 3):

Use the window function `LAG` with a `7 PRECEDING` frame to catch the values from 7 days ago, so that you can avoid using unnecessary subqueries or even self joins, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  date, Tname, Week,
  LAG(traffic,7) OVER (PARTITION BY tname ORDER BY tname,to_date(date,'mm/dd/yyyy')),
  AVG(traffic)   OVER (PARTITION BY week,tname)
FROM a
ORDER BY tname,week;

   date    | tname | week |  lag  |        avg        
-----------+-------+------+-------+-------------------
 5/1/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/2/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/3/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/4/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/5/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/6/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/7/2023  | ID1   | 18   |       | 7.492857142857143
 5/8/2023  | ID1   | 19   |  7.98 | 7.988333333333333
 5/9/2023  | ID1   | 19   |  4.44 | 7.988333333333333
 5/10/2023 | ID1   | 19   |  5.66 | 7.988333333333333
 5/11/2023 | ID1   | 19   | 10.01 | 7.988333333333333
 5/12/2023 | ID1   | 19   |  9.41 | 7.988333333333333
 5/13/2023 | ID1   | 19   |  6.71 | 7.988333333333333
(13 rows)
```

Note:

- this query assumes there is only one measurement per date/tname
- Consider changing the data type of "date" to `date`. I had to cast it to make the query work properly.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sdu6Ojc4)

Answer (score 2):

Try a left self-join as the following:

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.Tname,
       t1.week,
       t1.traffic,
       t2.traffic traffic_D7,
       AVG(t1.traffic) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.week) AS AVTraffic
FROM a t1 LEFT JOIN a t2
ON t1.date = t2.date + interval '7 day'
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nxjzR8YMQ4eGnH9BfHxgt8/0)